# Angular autocomplete md-selected-item-change double binding

Tags: angularjs

I am writing a program with two autocomplete boxes. The first box contains a series of object (lets call it obj1). This object contains an instance variable which is an array of type object 2. The second autocomplete box is the array. So , the user selects an item in box 1, then I use md-selected-item-change to call a method in my controller that initializes an array (lets call it arr) so that the second box is then populated with arr. Some pseudocode for example

```
 <md-autocomplete
      md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem"
      md-search-text="ctrl.searchText"
      md-selected-item-change="ctrl.getSnaps()"
      md-items="item in ctrl.sgs"
      md-item-text="item.name"
      md-min-length="0"
    <md-item-template>
      <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">
          {{item.display}}</span>
    </md-item-template>
    <md-not-found>
      No states matching "{{ctrl.searchText}}" were found.
    </md-not-found>
  </md-autocomplete>

  <md-autocomplete
      md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem"
      md-search-text="ctrl.searchText2"
      md-items="item in ctrl.snaps"
      md-item-text="item.name"
      md-min-length="0"
    <md-item-template>
      <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText2" md-highlight-flags="^i">
          {{item.display}}</span>
    </md-item-template>
    <md-not-found>
      No states matching "{{ctrl.searchText2}}" were found.
    </md-not-found>
  </md-autocomplete>
```

Upon doing this, the second box does not get populated. I think it doesn't support double binding. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you provide plunker or paste more code? Both md-autocomplete elements at least.

Comment: Edited. I dont have the code in front of me and its proprietary so i can't upload it exactly as is so i had to use examples. The getSnaps method just makes it so that the snaps variable = the array from the selected item